# A Borel-Cantelli problem showing $\sum P(E_k)<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $X_n, n ≥ 1$, be independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables, $S_n =\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k$, and let $a_n$ be real numbers such that $a_n/a_{n+1} \leq C$ for all $n$ and $$P(\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n/a_n = 0) = 1$$
Show that $\sum_{k≥1} P(|X_k| ≥ a_k) < ∞$.

Here are my thoughts: I want to try and show that if instead $P(|X_k| ≥ a_k) = ∞$ then it would imply $P(|X_k| ≥ a_k \text{ i.o.}) = 1$ (since they are independent)

and then somehow use this to show that there is a subsequence for which $\lim S_k/k \neq 0$ this subsequence will be pulled from all indices where $|X_k|\geq a_k$.  But I'm not sure how to fill in the details( I would need to use the fact that $a_n/a_{n+1} \leq C$.  I'm not sure if this is the right way, even though it seems pretty plausible.  Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

source: 2011 Qualifying exam https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Spring_2011/507.pdf

Comment: In the exam you quote they write $S_n/a_n$, not $S_n/n.$ Did you notice this?

Comment: ah yes, that was just a typo I made, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in addition to your assumptions you also need $a_n > 0$ (and thus implicitly $ C> 0$ since if you allow for negative $a_n$ you can find simple counterexamples to the statement.

The most direct way to approach this problem is not to use the common Borel Cantelli, but instead the [converse result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result). In the setting of this question this result tells us that:
$$
\sum_{k≥1} P(|X_k| ≥ a_k) = ∞ \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \limsup_k \frac{|X_k|}{a_k} \ge 1 \ \text{a.s.}
$$

Now we see that a.s. also $S_{n-1}/a_n \to 0.$ Indeed
$$
\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{a_n} \le C \frac{|S_{n-1}|}{a_{n-1}} \to 0 \ \text{a.s}. 
$$
(we can even choose the same nullset for the a.s. convergence) Now if we look outside of a nullset of the above limits holde true. All that is left to do is show that this is impossible. In fact let us consider a subsequence $n_k$ such that for some $\alpha\ge 1$
$$
\lim_k \frac{|X_{n_k}|}{a_{n_k}} = \alpha
$$
Then it follows that
$$
\underbrace{\frac{S_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}}}_{\to 0} = \underbrace{\frac{S_{n_k-1}}{a_{n_k}}}_{\to 0} + \underbrace{\frac{X_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}}}_{\to \pm \alpha}
$$
which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! One question, is it necessary for the limsup to be exactly 1 or could it be greater than 1 as well?

Comment: you are perfectly right: my bad. The limsup should be greater or equal to 1. I edited the question accordingly.